# Unit testing BackgroundWorker reporting progress

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, backgroundworker, reportprogress

The following class has a method that calls the `ReportProgress` method of a 'BackgroundWorker`:

```
public class Project
{
    protected System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker;

    public void progress(int percentage)
    {
        if (worker != null)
             worker.ReportProgress(percentage);
    }
}
```

How to go about testing the `progress` method? The aim would be to test that the worker method has its `ReportProgress` method called with the correct argument. Correct me if this approach is wrong.

What has been tried is using FakeItEasy to create a fake of the `BackgroundWorker`, but that yields the error: "non virtual methods can not be intercepted".

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc Consider leaving it behind.

Comment: Yes, a `Task` should probably be used instead. However, the whole project uses `BackgroundWorker`, and I don't think it can be changed now. Is there any way to test the above method as is?

Comment: @Al2110 Is it an option for you to replace `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run` and `IProgress<T>`? For further details please check [Stephen Cleary's excellent article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html)